# Basis of a complex vector space

Tags: linear-algebra

Is (1,1) , (1,i) a basis for $\mathbb{C}^2$? They are linearly independent but when I try expressing them as linear combinations I do not seem to be able to obtain every vector in $\mathbb{C}^2$. In particular, $(a+bi)(1,1) + (c+di)(1,i) = (a+c +i(b+d), a-d +i(b+c))$. From this expression I am not able to obtain any vector whose components have identical real part but differing imaginary parts.

Comment: Do you mean $\;\Bbb C^2\;$ over $\;\Bbb C\;$ ?

Answer (score 1):

An element in $\;\Bbb C^2_{\Bbb C}\;$ is an ordered pair $\;(\alpha,\beta)\;,\;\;a,b\in\Bbb C\;$ . Unless you meant something else, an element $\;a+bi\;,\;\;a,b,\in\Bbb R$ , is *a scalar* in $\;\Bbb C\;$ , not a vector in $\;\Bbb C^2\;$ , and then:

$$\binom\alpha\beta=\frac{\beta-\alpha i}{1-i}\binom11+\frac{\alpha-\beta}{1-i}\binom1i$$

assuming you meant the definition field is $\;\Bbb C\;$ , and then $\;\dim_{\Bbb C}\Bbb C^2=2\;$

Answer (score 0):

They are indeed independent, and there is two of them. Because $\mathbb C^2$ si a vector space of finite dimension $2$ over $\mathbb C$, you can definitely say that it is a basis.

Your calculation is correct, and if you want the coordinates of the vector $(u=u_1+iu_2,v=v_1+iv_2)$, you want

$$\begin{cases} a+c+i(b+d)=u_1+iu_2 \\ a-d+i(b+c)=v_1+iv_2 \end{cases}$$

so you need to solve the linear system

$$\begin{cases} a+c=u_1 \\ b+d=u_2 \\ a-d=v_1 \\ b+c=v_2\end{cases}$$

in order to find the coordinates you were looking for.

Can you take it from here ?